# android jrtplib

Tags: android, rtp

jni/jrtplib/include/jrtplib3/rtpsessionsources.h:50: error: non-static reference member 'jrtplib::RTPSession& jrtplib::RTPSessionSources::rtpsession', can't use default assignment operator

link to rtpsessionsource.h
http://research.edm.uhasselt.be/jori/jrtplib/documentation/rtpsessionsources_8h_source.html

anyone, please help me.

Comment: what are you trying to implement and what is this exactly?

Comment: I was trying to ndk-build jrtplib with jthread supported in android.after ndk-build it comes up with this error.error: non-static reference member 'jrtplib::RTPSession& jrtplib::RTPSessionSources::rtpsession', can't use default assignment operator

Answer (score 1):

All depends on how you wanna to build [`jrtplib`](http://research.edm.uhasselt.be/~jori/page/index.php?n=CS.Jrtplib)

I see 3 options here

- use existing build script from https://github.com/jimjh/JRTPLib-for-Android
- because `jrtplib` based on `cmake` build system, you can use https://github.com/taka-no-me/android-cmake
- write own `Android.mk`

Personally I used second option and my build script looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash

LIB=jrtplib-3.9.1
BUILD=$(PWD)/build
CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN=$(PWD)/android-cmake
BUILD_TYPE=Debug

mkdir -p $BUILD/armeabi-v7a
cd $BUILD/armeabi-v7a
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN/android.toolchain.cmake \
        -DANDROID_NDK=$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=$BUILD_TYPE -DANDROID_ABI="armeabi-v7a with NEON" \
        -DJRTPLIB_COMPILE_STATIC=ON \
        $LIB
cmake --build .

cd $ROOT

mkdir -p build/x86
cd $BUILD/x86
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN/android.toolchain.cmake \
        -DANDROID_NDK=$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=$BUILD_TYPE -DANDROID_ABI="x86" \
        -DJRTPLIB_COMPILE_STATIC=ON \
        $LIB
cmake --build .
```

PS I have build without [`jthread`](http://research.edm.uhasselt.be/~jori/page/index.php?n=CS.Jthread) support